# Which are nontrivial examples of analytical functions on Frechet spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a real linear topological space, which is a (separable) Frechet space, such that the topology on $X$ is generated by the countable family $\{p_n:n\in\omega\}$ of **norms** . A real-valued function $f$ is $X$ called *analytic*, provided $f$ is continuous and the restriction of  $f$ on each line of $X$ is an analytic function. We are interested in examples of  analytic functions $f$ on $X$ having no $n\in\omega $ such that $f$ is a continuous function on $(X, p_n)$.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: This is my first time that i hear about such functions and spaces. Please suggest me some references. Tnx :).

Comment: @M.Sina: Thank you for the interest to our investigation. In fact, this question points in the mathematical domain of my coauthor, who handles functional analysis (I finished postgraduate courses at the topology chair and wrote the PhD. thesis on paratopological groups), so and I forwarded your query to him. He answered the following.

Comment: If you are interested in this theme, than he can provide you more information. But for the beginning, just to introduce you to this domain, he said that, roughly speaking, a polynomial on a linear topological space is a restriction of a polylinear map on the diagonal, and a function $f$ on such a space is analytic, provided $f$ has in each point a local presentation as a convergent sum of polynomials.

Comment: The notion of a Fréchet space is well known and the topology on it is generated by a family of **seminorms**. Fréchet spaces, endowed with a system of **norms** are not considered separately, we consider such spaces for our specific purposes.

Comment: The theory of analytical functions in Banach (more generally, in locally convex spaces) was formed at the second half of the previous century, though first results for it were obtained somewhat earlier. There is a bunch of articles in this domain. Main book references are the following.

Comment: [Din] Dineen S. Complex analysis on infinite dimensional spaces / S. Dineen -- Verlag, Berlin, New York: Monographs in Mathematics, Springer, 1999. -- 543 p.

It is the most advanced and complicated book. If you are interested in it, I try to obtain a file of it from my coauthor, who can have it.

Comment: A book on theory of polynomials and analytical functions on Banach spaces (mainly, on complex):


[Muj] Mujica J. Complex Analysis in Banach Spaces / J. Mujica -- Amsterdam, New York, Oxford: North-Holland, 1986. -- 434 p.


It is an introductive course for these who know the standard course of the functional analysis.

Comment: [Her] Hervé M. Analyticity in Infiite Dimensional Spaces / M. Hervé --  Berlin, New York: de Gruyter   Stud. in Math.,  Walter de Gruyter, Vol. 10, 1989. -- 206 p.  

The theme of this book is close to the previous, but it is somewhat different. He has a file  with a photocopy of this book, but it has a size about 100 M and my coauthor cannot upload it now. If you are interested in this book, I get it from him and upload.

Comment: [Bon] Bong Chae S. Holomorphy and Calculus in Normed Spaces / S. Bong Chae -- New York -- Basel: Pure and Applied Mathematics, A Series of Monographs and Textbooks, Marcel Dekker, Inc., 1985. -- 421 p.

This is a normal book, similar to the Mujica’s one.

Comment: I am a graduate student in the field of topological groups, and interested in The topics that are a combination of several branches of mathematics (For example Topology+vector space=Topological vector spaces). I will use Mujica's book to primary.